# Cannot read and parse XML file in Meteor

Tags: javascript, xml, file, meteor

Im using [xml2jws](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/xml2js) and **Meteor**. Ive tried both **with** fs and **without** like the examples in docs

my js file **With fs**

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var fs = require('fs');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser(); 
export const extractEntities = function (file) {
fs.readFile('./xmlFile.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        console.log('Done');
    });
});
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function
    at extractEntities (packages.js:8)
    at PackageUpload.componentDidMount (PackageUpload.js:36)
    at commitLifeCycles (modules.js?hash=603e8fa158a1fc409b1d0d581586111b31091ac9:24142)
```

js file **Without fs**

```
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

export const extractEntities = () => {

    parseString('./xmlFile.xml', function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        return result;
    })
}
```

In this case, **it returns undefined**

However, when I pass an xml string in `parseString`it works. But in my app, Im uploading it as a file from disk and its passed to `extractEntities`. It has no arguments in this example because im testing parsing the file first, then will test an uploaded xml file.

This is my directory

```
Directory 
   file.js
   xmlFile.xml
```

Comment: You can't pass a path to `parseString` it will try to parse the path as XML. You have to load the file yourself. If you are running in a web browser, you may not use `fs`. You will need to make an http request for the using fetch or something.

Comment: @AluanHaddad im running `file.js` in backend. Its not a react component, does this change anything?

Comment: Running in NodeJS, `'fs'` must be available. It looks like the error is coming from a call to `componentDidMount` so it sure sounds like a React component but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @AluanHaddad yeah, it is available and I tried to use it. A react component triggers the function but the file read happens in the back end, off react.